# C# entity framework when join two table

Tags: c#

I have some tables,using Entity Framework

**UserTable**

- UserID

**BookTable**

- BookID
- BookName

**OwnTable**

- UserID
- BookID

now I can use:

```
uw.ownRepository.GetData().where(v=>v.userid=1).select(o=>o.Book)
```

to get all the book I own.But If I want to get all the books , and note that whether the user own it or not

I have some solution

1.

select all the book,
then for each one select once

stupid solution = ="

2.

```
    var s = from book in uw.bookRepository.GetData()                    
    join own in uw.ownRepository.GetData() on book.Id equals like.Id into ps
    from o in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {bookName =book.name,IsOwn =o==null};
```

just some pseudocode.

I tried it and works fine.

But I'm wondering if there is another better solution

if I want to select a strong type like

```
    select new Book{bookName =book.name,bookType=book.bookType, IsOwn =o==null};
```

in this case , if I have many field in bookTable , i have to assign every field.

Does anybody have some idea?

Comment: please try to revise your question, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) the guide `:)`

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple. You want all books so you want to start your lambda express on books entity. In the example here, I have selected an anonymous type. However, you can select your predefined type.

```
Books.GetData().Select(b=> new {name = b.BookName , DoIOwnThisBook = OwnTable.GetData().Where()})
```

Comment: I know this solution, it's same as mine.
My question is if I already use entityframework to generate one class, why do I need to use anonymous type or a new class , maybe we could just add a field in old class and quick assign it

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot assign to already existing items in the select. You have to create a new one. You could however add a field to your class and create a new instance of the class and assign it.

Comment: @CloudsanChen As you understand, selecting all books is not a problem, and also selecting books by certain condition is also not a problem. However, when you want to select all books with ownership information, it creates a join and you want to populate IsOwn field in the book so you must specify it at the time of creation.